# Paginação Dinâmica em tabela com AngularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, vraptor

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recupero esses dados de uma API Rest com Vraptor. Gostaria de exibir apenas dois itens por página, porém não sei por onde começar. Implementei essa paginação utilizando o [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started).

Como faço para fazer uma consulta dinâmica e exibir apenas dois itens por página?

**Back-end:**

Controller:

```
@Get
@Path("/colaboradores")
public void listarTodos() {
        result.use(Results.json())
        .withoutRoot()
        .from(colaboradorDAO.listarColaboradores())
        .serialize();
}
```

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Colaborador> listarColaboradores() {
        List<Colaborador> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Colaborador.listar");
            lista = consulta.list();
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

---

**Front-end:**

Controller:

```
angular.module("oraculo").controller("colaboradorController", function($scope, $routeParams, $location, colaboradorAPI){

 $scope.tamanhoMaximo = 6;
 $scope.totalItems = 175;
 $scope.currentPage = 1;

 ...//Código Omitido
```

Página:

```
...//Trecho omitido
</table>
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="tamanhoMaximo" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
<pre>Page: {{currentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
public List<Colaborador> listarColaboradores(Integer paginaInicio, Integer paginaFim) {
    List<Colaborador> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = null;
    try {
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();

        Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Colaborador.listar");
        consulta.setFirstResult(paginaInicio);
        consulta.setMaxResults(paginaFim);

        lista = consulta.list();
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

No teu serviço pode passar dois parâmetros definindo o inicio e final da pagina. No teu caso, por exemplo, seria na primeira consulta: 0 e 2, na segunda consulta: 2 e 4 e assim por diante.

Comment: eu passaria esses parâmetros por GET mesmo ou por POST?

Comment: Vc pode passar via GET

Comment: Entendi, eu to passando apenas a currentPage, esta quase dando certo porém ele ainda não está paginando da forma correta. O que eu passo nesse `MaxResults` ?

Comment: E quando pulo pra próxima página ele repete o ultimo registro da pagina anterior, além do registro com código = 1 não aparecer na consulta

Comment: MaxResults vc define até qual pagina será retornada. Imagine a seguinte situação. Vc tem 100 registros no banco. Passando FirstResult=10 e MaxResults=20 o hibernate irá retornar apenas os registros entre essa faixa, ou seja, registros entre 10 e 20, entendeu?

Comment: Ele não repete o ultimo registro, passa para o próximo

Comment: Entendi, como não exibo ele na próxima página?

Comment: No retorno do teu serviço vc seta $scope.<nome_objeto> = <retorno do serviço>